# changing pointers(increasing , decreasing)?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

the program below shows *q=46 but q points to an address that is not defined because it points to : p-1 so its not pointing to p or m but another address(because of -1)
then how can it be *q=46
i think it must have a garbage number based on what ive learnt
i hope you get what im trying to say because im not native speaker

```
int m = 44;
int* p = &m;
int& r = m;
int n = (*p++);
int* q = p – 1;
r = *(--p) + 1;
++*q;
```

the exercise wants the amount of each variable and pointer and reference above once the program is run
i tested it with a program

output:

```
p=0022fa00
*p=46
&p=0022f9f4
&n=0022f9dc
n=44
m=46
q=0022fa00  <<<<<<<
r=46
*q=46  <<<<<<<
&m=0022fa00
```

i thought maybe it's because of int n=(*p++) but i think that shouldnt be the reason because that statement must increment the number in p not the address

Comment: @user3783574 please consider reading the formatting guidelines at the [help] and read [ask] it would considerably help you get answers faster for your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int m = 44;//m=44
int* p = &m;//p has address of m *p=44
int& r = m;// r is allias(nickname) of m (*p m r is same)=44
int n = (*p++);//n=44 *p=garbage m=44 r=44 p is m's address+1
// *p++ means give *p then increase p(not *p)
int* q = p - 1;//q shows m's address *q=44
r = *(--p) + 1;//*(--p) means m r= m+1=45 r=45 m=45 because r is allias of m *q=45
++*q;//increase r=46 m=46 (*q)=46
```

It is what happens at there.I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

> i thought maybe it's because of int n=(*p++) but i think that shouldnt be the reason because that statement must increment the number in p not the address

Nope. `*p++` is `*(p++)`, not `(*p)++`.

Comment: oookay didnt know that
but * is in the parenthesize not out of it
doesnt it make a difference?